# OPTIONS always returns 200

Tags: webserver, cors

I am testing out cors on a website and an options request always returns 200 even if the requesting origin isn't authorized. If the origin isn't authorized they just do not add the headers. Does this fit the spec? It seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected and acceptable per the spec.  A non-200 response can and should be returned when a network or server error occurs.  In the absence of a server or network error, the response headers should indicate which origins and methods are allowed.  If your origin, for example, isn't among those present in the ACAO header in the response, then the user agent will abort and not send the original request.